# How do I prevent anonymous users from deleting/editing my documents in couchDB?

Tags: security, function, validation, couchdb

I know that CouchDB does not allow non-admin users to edit/delete design documents, but how do I prevent them from editing/deleting all documents?

The only info I could find is that user permissions can be set with validation functions. I am a little confused on how I would write a validation function to do this/where validation functions live. Are they all in the _users DB?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another way to restrict access to your database is to configure the `[couch_httpd_auth]` with `require_valid_user:true`

Then every request must send credentials to login to your couchdb.

Comment: For my use-case, this is much simpler and more effective than the accepted answer.  My goal was blocking **all** anonymous access, not just specific actions against specific documents.  This answer does that.

Answer (score 8):

It's an easy: just create design document with [`validate_doc_update`](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/ddocs.html#validate-document-update-functions) function in database where you'd like to control documents that does something like this:

```
function(newDoc, oldDoc, userCtx, secObj){ 
    if('_admin' in userCtx.roles) return; // skip anonymous in Admin Party case;
    if(!userCtx.name && newDoc._deleted){
      throw({'forbidden': 'auth first before delete something'});
    }
}
```

The idea is simple: if [`userCtx`](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/json-structure.html#userctx-object) has no name specified this means that user is anonymous and if our new document version has special field `_deleted` set as `true` - document going to be deleted (but changes doesn't saved on disk yet). So we checks for these fields and throwing an forbidden exception if condition was satisfied. We're also make an exception for Admin Party case there is everyone nameless, but has `_admin` role, so we need to skip them. And now on any attempt to delete regular document by anonymous user he will receive next HTTP response:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: CouchDB/1.3.0 (Erlang OTP/R15B03)
Date: Thu, 25 Apr 2013 18:48:51 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 68
Cache-Control: must-revalidate

{"error":"forbidden","reason":"auth first before delete something"}
```